# change the date formats to modified ISO date in multiple column in each line using awk or sed

Tags: linux, date, awk, sed

Input file

```
xyz|name1|address1|19600221|M|country1|20200129|etc1
xyz|name2|address2|19610321|M|country2|20200118|etc1
xyz|name3|address3|19520217|M|country3||etc1
xyz|name4|address4|19611111|M|country4||etc1
```

expected output

```
xyz|name1|address1|1960-02-21|M|country1|2020-01-29|etc1
xyz|name2|address2|1961-03-21|M|country2|2020-01-18|etc1
xyz|name3|address3|1952-02-17|M|country3||etc1
xyz|name4|address4|1961-11-11|M|country4||etc1
```

Code that I used

```
awk -F"|" '{OFS="|";$4=strftime("%Y-%m-%d", $4); print$0}' input.txt
```

and redirect the output to new file and ran the same for the 7th column but the result is not as expected and I got the below

```
 xyz|name1|address1|1960-02-21|M|country1|1970-08-22|etc1
    xyz|name2|address2|1961-03-21|M|country2|1970-08-22|etc1
    xyz|name3|address3|1952-02-17|M|country3|1970-01-01|etc1
    xyz|name4|address4|1961-11-11|M|country4|1970-01-01|etc1
```

I couldn't understand why the column 7 output is different? Any advise on what is wrong here?

Comment: `1961-0-321`? What planet is that?

Comment: planet typo! sorry

Comment: `strftime` expects seconds since epoch. `strftime("%Y-%m-%d",19610321)` = `1970-08-16`

Comment: just a general note: whenever you can modify formats of datetimes inside awk using only the `string` functions, do it, don't use the `time` functions.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following. Written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="|"
}
{
  $7=($7!=""?substr($7,1,4)"-"substr($7,5,2)"-"substr($7,7):"")
}
1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                         ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                                        ##Starting BEGIN section from here.
  FS=OFS="|"                                  ##Starting field separator and output field separator as | here.
}
{
  $7=($7!=""?substr($7,1,4)"-"substr($7,5,2)"-"substr($7,7):"")  ##Checking condition if 7th field is NOT NULL then using sub string to make them into the date exact format.
}
1                                             ##1 will print current edited/non-edited line here.
' Input_file                                  ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

***NOTE:*** In case you have one or multiple columns which have dates and you want to change them to `yyyy-mm-dd` format etc then you could use a for loop like `for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^[0-9]{8}$/){substr(..code above)...}`

Answer (score 3):

You could use [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) for this:

```
$ sed -E 's/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/\1-\2\-\3/g' input.txt
xyz|name1|address1|1960-02-21|M|country1|2020-01-29|etc1
xyz|name2|address2|1961-03-21|M|country2|2020-01-18|etc1
xyz|name3|address3|1952-02-17|M|country3||etc1
xyz|name4|address4|1961-11-11|M|country4||etc1
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, but an extended comment.

@thanasisp's comment is on the mark. @RavinderSingh13's answer shows how to split apart and then join the date pieces into the desired format. If you want to use the time functions you still need to do that:

```
# reformatdate.awk

BEGIN {FS = OFS = "|"}

function formatDate(d,    t) {
  t = mktime(substr(d,1,4) " " substr(d,5,2) " " substr(d,7,2) " 0 0 0")
  return strftime("%Y-%m-%d", t)
}

{
  $4 = formatDate($4)
  if ($7) $7 = formatDate($7)
  print
}
```

Then

```
$ gawk -f reformatdate.awk input.txt
xyz|name1|address1|1960-02-21|M|country1|2020-01-29|etc1
xyz|name2|address2|1961-03-21|M|country2|2020-01-18|etc1
xyz|name3|address3|1952-02-17|M|country3||etc1
xyz|name4|address4|1961-11-11|M|country4||etc1
```

Comment: Very well presented. I have seen that as a caveat of awk: In order to make a (real) time, you have to give a specific format to mktime(). there is no (python-like) strptime(), only strftime().

Comment: by the way, it is not only an extended comment, but an answer too.

Comment: @thanasisp GNU awk has a `strptime()` but it's in the gawk extension library, `gawkextlib` along with the JSON, CSV and XML parser extensions, etc. See my comments at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/608568/awk-using-time-difference-in-miliseconds-in-the-report#comment1136183_608568 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/608568/awk-using-time-difference-in-miliseconds-in-the-report#comment1136191_608568 for more info.

Comment: @EdMorton I guess there are reasons for not being a standard function (perfomance, compatibility?) but I haven't tried it.

Comment: @thanasisp The main arguments from the providers seemed to be a) not every platform that has gawk has an underlying strptime() primitive that gawk could call and, b) they simply want to add all new functionality to gawkextlib..